# Moving Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Project To A New Directory

Tags: visual-web-developer, visual-web-developer-2010

I attempted to move a VWD project to a new directory but got the following error on building:

```
Error   1   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  P:\MY DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NetworkOperationsDashboard\NetworkOperationsDashboard\Web.config    28
```

I Googled for solutions but none of them worked for me so I just created a new project in the correct directory and added all of my old files.  However, now the aspx.cs file cannot seem to read the .aspx file -- I keep getting a lot of symbol "whatever" not found in this context.  The "Codefile" and "Inherits" values are correct but the DOCTYPE declaration is underlined in blue and hovering over it gives roughly the same error as above.

Line 28 of the webconfig file is:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

But this was working fine before I started moving things.  However, if I run the web app without building first, this line throws this error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

I have tried editing the solution file in a text editor to replace all of the old path names with the new ones but this does not fix it.

When I first wrote this project the solution ended up in one directory and all of the other files ended up in another.  This was my first project so I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I just want to tidy it up now.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT:

I just started a new project in the correct directory and cut and paste all of my old files into the new ones.  It seems like this should be fool proof -- and the error messages are gone -- but the .aspx.cs file still can't seem to see the .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

So I deleted the .aspx.designer.cs file, right-clicked on the .aspx file and chose "Convert To Web Application".  Not sure why, but this did the trick.